# Set IP adress for the wifi hotspot on OSX

Tags: wifi, settings, network

If I share my ethernet over WiFi I would like to specify the IP address of the hotspot (for now it defaults to 10.0.2.1). Can this be set somewhere in system settings?

Note: the ethernet is not connected. I just run a local web server that should be accessible by some clients connection to my hotspot (and therefore I should have a fix IP address).

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT, this is managed by the process com.apple.InternetSharing. When it is enabled, the file `/etc/bootpd.plist` is created. Here it has your IP address 10.0.2.1

However, this file is deleted and recreated when Internet Sharing restarts, so modifying it is pointless. I bet that the `defaults` command can be used to set a new IP address, however `defaults read` and `sudo defaults read` do not cite anything related to "com.apple.InternetSharing".

I know this isn't a complete answer, but if you find whatever is creating `/etc/bootpd.plist` you'll probably accomplish your goal. You may want to read [this earlier question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17545/questions-about-how-internet-sharing-works) about Internet Sharing.